# i'm trying to create a react.js project but the same error is occuring in my every project about index.js file, how to resolve this error?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babel-loader

ERROR in ./src/index.js 9:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (9:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
| ReactDOM.render(

> <React.StrictMode>
> |

****here is my index.js file code****

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import _ from 'lodash';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

*****here is my webpack.config.js file code*****

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require( 'html-webpack-plugin' );
const path = require( 'path' );
module.exports = {
   mode:"development",
   context: __dirname,
   entry: './src/index.js',
   output: {
      path: path.resolve( __dirname, 'dist' ),
      filename: 'main.js',
      publicPath: '/',},
   devServer: {historyApiFallback: true },
   module: {
      rules: [
         {
            test: /\.js?$/,
            exclude:'/node_module/',
            use: 'babel-loader',
         },
         {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
         },
         {
            test: /\.(png|j?g|svg|gif|jpg)?$/,
            use: 'file-loader'
         }
]
   },
   plugins: [
      new HtmlWebPackPlugin({template: path.resolve( __dirname, 'public/index.html' ),
         filename: 'index.html'
      })
   ]
};
```

*****here is my package.json file*****

```
{
  "name": "create-burger-builder",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babelify": "^10.0.0",
    "browserify": "^16.5.2",
    "core-util-is": "^1.0.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode=development",
    "prod": "webpack --mode=production"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^4.2.2",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
}
```

*****here is my .babelrc file code*****

```
{
    "presets": [
    [ "@babel/preset-env", {
    "modules": false,
    "targets": {
    "browsers": [
    "last 2 Chrome versions",
    "last 2 Firefox versions",
    "last 2 Safari versions",
    "last 2 iOS versions",
    "last 1 Android version",
    "last 1 ChromeAndroid version",
    "ie 11"
    ]
    }
    } ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [ "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties" ]
    }
```

*****here is my index.html file code*****

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

***** here is my App.js file code*****

```
import React from 'react';
import Layout from './components/Layout/Layout';
import BurgerBuilder from './containers/burgerBuilder/BurgerBuilder';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
  
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Could you try renaming the file to `.jsx` and add `test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,` to your `babel-loader` config instaed of just `/\.js?$/`.

Comment: i've tried both one by one test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, as well as just /\.js?$/
but the responce is same...
please help.!

Comment: he also means to add the file extension, instead of .js to .jsx, additionally to the loader in webpack config file. This is the error.